# Is there a list of chess openings online without names

Tags: opening, analysis, pgn

I have been searching for a list of eco (Encyclopaedia of Chess Openings) chess openings online by moves rather than by name so that I don't have to sort through thousands of names but I can not find such a list anywhere. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

https://www.365chess.com/opening.php for instance has what you look for.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're exactly looking for but an opening explorer would probably do the job.

On the [lichess analysis board](https://lichess.org/analysis) you can use the opening explorer by clicking on the book icon (the left-most button at the bottom of the right panel).

There you can check the most commonly played moves from any given position. You can filter for master games only, for all games played on Lichess or for the games you have played yourself on the site. You can also get a list of full games where the position was reached.

Comment: here is the source for that https://github.com/lichess-org/chess-openings

Comment: what i meant is a list of eco (Encyclopaedia of Chess Openings) opening without names